# Yarn Workspaces multiple node_modules folders

Tags: yarnpkg, yarn-workspaces

Currently working on a project with yarn workspaces.
After creating a few packages and then running yarn install on root level multiple nested as well as one root level node_modules folders are generated.

Is this behavior normal or am I doing something wrong?